# Make srcset attribute work for Internet Explorer in broken HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, frontend

I have this broken img tag and it works fine in Chrome and Edge browser. It loads all the images even though there is something wrong with the src attribute.

```
<a href="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/feestverlichting-voor-de-achtertuin/">
  <img src="<img width="806" height="605" src="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg 806w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-152x114.jpg 152w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-768x576.jpg 768w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-253x190.jpg 253w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-506x380.jpg 506w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-600x450.jpg 600w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-200x150.jpg 200w" sizes="(max-width: 806px) 100vw, 806px" />
</a>
```

However, Internet Explorer refuses to loads the images. I know this should be fixed at the source, but I am not responsible for that.

Is there some kind of frontend fix we can apply so that the images will load in IE?

I have tried removing the src attribute all together but to no avail

```
jQuery( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail" ).removeAttr('src');
```

Comment: Firstly, your HTML seems broken as you have a nested `<img />`. Secondly, this is the first hit for 'srcset polyfill', should be worth a shot: https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is broken. It is not correct to nest img tags. If you can't fix the terrible HTML, maybe try some js to pull the url out of the malformed src attribute of the first tag??

```
  $('a img').each(function(){
    $(this).parents('a').html($(this).attr('src'))
  })
```